# com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView

Tags: android, listview, pull-to-refresh

**I made an Activity page to this Fragment page and do necessary changes that fragment need but i got this error please help me out of this.** 
I have an activity which have two fragments and this one is one of those two.And though it is a list view if i click on it the 2nd one is display at the other side of same activity page. That is all the main functionality that i want to do.

```
public class FreagmentMainCategory extends Fragment{

    private LinearLayout llLayoutmain;
    private FragmentActivity faActivitymain;
    private ListView lstCategoryList;
    private SelectCategoryTask mAuthTask = null;
    private View mServiceStatusView;
    CategoryDetails mainCategory;
    private categoryListAdapter adapterList;    
    static final int MENU_MANUAL_REFRESH = 0;
    static final int MENU_DISABLE_SCROLL = 1;
    static final int MENU_SET_MODE = 2;
    static final int MENU_DEMO = 3;
    private View lstListView;
    private PullToRefreshListView mPullRefreshListView;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //faActivitymain  = (FragmentActivity)  super.getActivity();
         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment_main,container, false);

        this.getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
        FontUtils.setCustomFont(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mainView), getActivity().getAssets());

        lstListView= view.findViewById(R.id.lstCategoryView);
        mPullRefreshListView = (PullToRefreshListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lstCategory);
        // Set a listener to be invoked when the list should be refreshed.
        mPullRefreshListView.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener<ListView>() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh(PullToRefreshBase<ListView> refreshView) {
                String label = DateUtils.formatDateTime(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), System.currentTimeMillis(),
                        DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL);

                // Update the LastUpdatedLabel
                refreshView.getLoadingLayoutProxy().setLastUpdatedLabel(label);

                // Do work to refresh the list here.
                new GetDataTask().execute();
            }
        });
        mPullRefreshListView.setOnLastItemVisibleListener(new OnLastItemVisibleListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLastItemVisible() {

            }
        }); 
        lstListView=(View)view.findViewById(R.id.lstCategoryView);

        lstCategoryList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lstCategory);//got error in this line    

        //lstCategoryList = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment_main, container, false);
        lstCategoryList = mPullRefreshListView.getRefreshableView();

        registerForContextMenu(lstCategoryList);


        mServiceStatusView = view.findViewById(R.id.service_status);
        //txtTitle=(TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.serviceText);
        //txtTitle.setText(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.title_select_category));     
        showProgress(true); 
        mAuthTask = new SelectCategoryTask();
        mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
        lstCategoryList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,long arg3) {    
                    Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    //bundle.putInt(key, value);

                //Intent subCategoryIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplication(),FragmentSubCategory.class);              
                bundle.putString("MainCategoryId", mainCategory.masterinfo.get(position-1).maincatid);
                bundle.putString("MainCategoryName", mainCategory.masterinfo.get(position-1).maincatname);
                //subCategoryIntent.putExtra("MainCategoryId", mainCategory.masterinfo.get(position-1).maincatid);
                //subCategoryIntent.putExtra("MainCategoryName", mainCategory.masterinfo.get(position-1).maincatname);
                //getActivity().getApplication().startActivity(subCategoryIntent);  
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_service, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
    private void showProgress(final boolean show) {
        // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
        // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
        // the progress spinner.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
            int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                    android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

            mServiceStatusView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mServiceStatusView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime)
                    .alpha(show ? 1 : 0)
                    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            mServiceStatusView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE
                                    : View.GONE);
                        }
                    });

            lstListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lstListView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime)
                    .alpha(show ? 0 : 1)
                    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            lstCategoryList.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE
                                    : View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    });         

        } else {
            // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
            // and hide the relevant UI components.
            mServiceStatusView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            lstListView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);         

        }
    }

    public class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Simulates a background job.
            ServerAccess sa=new ServerAccess();
            mainCategory=sa.GetMainCategory();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            if(mainCategory==null){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.error_check_network), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                lstCategoryList.setAdapter(null);
            }else if(mainCategory.code.equals("MOB01")){
                adapterList=new categoryListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), mainCategory.masterinfo);
                lstCategoryList.setAdapter(null);
            }else if(mainCategory.code.equals("MOB02")){

                lstCategoryList.setAdapter(null);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.error_genric_error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                lstCategoryList.setAdapter(null);
            }


            // Call onRefreshComplete when the list has been refreshed.
            mPullRefreshListView.onRefreshComplete();

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

    public class SelectCategoryTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {          
            ServerAccess sa=new ServerAccess();
            mainCategory=sa.GetMainCategory();          
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);
            if(mainCategory==null){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.error_check_network), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                lstCategoryList.setAdapter(null);
            }else if(mainCategory.code.equals("MOB01")){
                adapterList=new categoryListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), mainCategory.masterinfo);
                lstCategoryList.setAdapter(adapterList);
            }else if(mainCategory.code.equals("MOB02")){
                lstCategoryList.setAdapter(null);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.error_genric_error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                lstCategoryList.setAdapter(null);
            }           
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);
        }
    }
    class categoryListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {        
        List<Category> mainItems;
        Context myContext;
        public categoryListAdapter(Context context, List<Category> items) {
            myContext = context;
            mainItems = items;            

        }
        public int getCount() {           
            return mainItems.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int index) {           
            return mainItems.get(index);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) { 
            return position;
        }        

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent    ) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(myContext);          
            TextView tv = new TextView(myContext);
            tv.setText(mainItems.get(position).maincatname);
            tv.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            tv.setTextSize(16);
            tv.setPadding(20, 20, 0, 20);
            tv.setTextColor(myContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.BlackColor));
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
            (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            layout.addView(tv,lp);           
            return layout;
        }
    }
```

}

Here Is my xml Code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mainView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/bg_main"
tools:context=".FreagmentMainCategory" >


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lstCategoryView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/serviceHeaderBar"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- The PullToRefreshListView replaces a standard ListView widget. -->

    <com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
        android:id="@+id/lstCategory"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="#19000000"
        android:dividerHeight="4dp"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/service_status"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/progress_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/loadingBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/service_status_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:tag="normal"
            android:text="@string/title_please_wait"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/BlackColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/MainSize" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: are you looking for swipe to refresh like new gmail app

Comment: Sir i had some functionality issues and i got it, btw thank you so much for your precious time for me..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PullToRefreshListView` is a wrapper around the `ListView`, it does not extend `ListView`, so you can't cast it directly. You can cast the return value of `findViewById` to `PullToRefreshListView` and call getRefreshableView() to retrieve the underlaying `ListView`. This line

`lstCategoryList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lstCategory);`

should be

`lstCategoryList = ((PullToRefreshListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lstCategory)).getRefreshableView();`

Android has its own [SwipeToRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) widget. Are you sure you want still to use `PullToRefreshListView`?

Comment: It worked sir thank you so much and I know sir android has its own Swipe ToRefreshLayout but  though i am so new to android and its an existing project of our community so cant change the libraries so try to understand.